# Disable add roster in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

Is it possible to disable "add roster" for users from client in ejabberd?
I just want to manage rosters subscriptions with the admin or code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot disable roster add in standard modules as it does not conform to XMPP. However, you can write you own roster plugin to manage the roster of your users and implement custom rules in your plugin.

Comment: I would also like to have the ability to prevent a subscription request from reaching the other user. I have only been using ejabberd for a couple of days and have managed to get a basic plugin loaded. I'm attaching a hook to the roster_in_subscription event but when it fires an error is thrown and I'm having trouble debugging even when running in live mode. Probably doesn't help than I'm also new to Erlang. Any tips or even an example would be greatly appreciated, although I have to say that I've only been able to get as far as I have thanks to the great documentation you guys provide.